# Will a local SMTP Server/Agent solve my issue?

Tags: email

I fully admit I don't know all the proper terms here, but I'm hoping I can explain my issue well enough that someone will be able to tell me what I need.

I have some devices on my network (APC AP9617 UPS Network Management Cards) which can send email via a local SMTP server. There is no provision for authenticating against remote SMTP servers, and these cards can only send messages and will not receive them.

I would like to have these cards send email through an Outlook.com email account (utilizing smtp.office365.com), but Microsoft of course requires authentication in order to connect and send emails.

I'm wondering if I could set up a local SMTP Server/Agent/Relay (I don't know the proper term) that would act as a local point to send emails, and then this *something* would connect to Outlook.com to send the emails to recipients.

I'm unsure of what application I would need to do this, however, and would welcome any advice or tips. I have a server running Ubuntu Linux that I can run it on, and if I could run it in a Docker container that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft of course requires authentication in order to connect and
>   send emails.

That's not correct. You need to use option 2 at the link below if you're sending email only to your own domain, or option 3 if you need to send email to other domains.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3

Comment: Since I need to send emails outside of my domain (I have no domain here so I assume everything is outside) option 3 is my only choice, and the first step of that is to be using a public static IP address, which I don't have. I'm sorry but I don't think any of the 3 options there are viable for me.